# pagination not working correctly in extjs

Tags: ajax, json, extjs, proxy, store

in the JSON i am getting total as 67 but on grid only two records gets displayed. Paging toolbar shows msg "Displaying 1 - 2 of 2" and next and previous button are also disabled 
Below is my js file's code.
how to verify if totalProperty is getting right total count ?

Ext.onReady(function(){

```
var simpsonsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    pageSize: 2,
    autoLoad: false,
    buffered: true,
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        pageParam: undefined,
        url: '/apex/getPatientData',
        startParam: 'start',
        limitParam: 'limit',
        noCache: false,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    },

});
simpsonsStore.load({
    params: {
        start: 0,
        limit: 2
    }
});
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        store: simpsonsStore, 
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your JSON doens't have a record of 
`totalProperty: 'total'` you need to return the number of all the records in this field

`{
    'total': 67,
    'items': [{
         ....
    }]
}`

Answer (score 0):

Two records are only ever being displayed as you have set the limit param to 2:

```
params: {
            start: 0,
            limit: 2
        }
```

Also your pageSize on the store is set to 2, so when it loads the data it considers a page of data in your store as a max of 2 records. See the docs - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-pageSize

Comment: even if i increase the limit (say 10) the grid gets loaded with  10 records and msg on paging toolbar says "Displaying 1 - 10 of 10", however total is 67 this is JSON response :   0: {rnum: 1, begin: "0", end: "10", total: 67, name: "1A", email: "Guruprit",…}. I think total property is not getting mapped correctly but i dont know how to verify if totalProperty is set correctly in reader.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your problem looks to be the structure of your json response.

@nniicc was on the right track and your JSON proves this as you are returning the total in the row of data, not as a separate property of your JSON object

> {rnum: 1, begin: "0", end: "10", total: 67, name: "1A", email:
>   "Guruprit",…}

So should be more like this

```
{
    'total': 67,
    'items': [{rnum: 1, begin: "0", end: "10", name: "1A", email: "Guruprit",…},
...]
}
```